# How to load different nib for iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nib

I would like to load a different .xib for my root view when my app is running on an iPad. I have tried to do as you can see from the code below, however what happens is the thread goes into the correct if statement so it identifies that it's an iPad however when the view loads it loads the iPhone version of the view.

Here is my code, I am trying to decide in the app delegate which nib to load for the rootView:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //Add status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewControlleriPad" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    }


    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; //Adds RootViewController to the NavigationController interface
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}; // navigation titles
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // navigation buttons
```

Comment: Do you notice your code, you have been setting the root view controller in two different places. If you remove the code to set root view controller outside the if else conditions, it should work fine.

Comment: that adds the view correctly to the window, however it dose not add the window to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rework this line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; //Adds RootViewController to the NavigationController interface
```

which is what's goofing up your results.

Comment: I tried this **[self.window setRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];** and it works perfectly!

Comment: Sorry, but `[self.window setRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];` is honestly not doing what you think it's doing. Re-Read that assignment carefully.

Comment: Maybe written like that: `[self.window setRootViewController:[self.window rootViewController]];`?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want to have a navigation controller from the get go. So programmatically create your navigation controller, set your device-specific RootViewController as the navigation controller's root (or initial) view, THEN set your window's root view to the navigation controller.

Comment: yep, that about sums it up.. I am going to do some research now. The thing being is in MainWindow.xib I have added the window and the navigation controller in their.. so I use IBOutlet for the window and navigation controller.. Im not really sure how to override them in code.

Comment: I havent been able to figure this out, I think its something to do with how I am using IBOutlet on window and rootview.